# How come blasters don't shoot straight?

Tags: star-wars

How come blasters don't shoot straight?  Lots of missed shots.

Comment: How does missed shots lead you to believe that blasters don't shoot straight?  Are you trying to say that the reason people don't always hit their target is because guns don't shoot straight?

Comment: It's an old Cracked article with broken links, so I'm not 100% on its correctness, but [The Biggest Star Wars Plot Hole, Explained By Science](http://www.cracked.com/article_18858_the-biggest-star-wars-plot-hole-explained-by-science.html) answers this question.  And it's not due to shoddily-made blasters.

Comment: Stormtroopers aren't actually that bad... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/are-all-stormtroopers-as-poor-soldiers-as-the-ones-in-the-movies

Answer (score 7):

Actually, depending on the level of Canon you are looking for, that's not an unreasonable question, at least as far as Stormtrooper use is concerned.

If you accept the [Games](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight_II:_Jedi_Outcast) as being [valid sources of information](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/E-11_blaster_rifle#Description), then

> Stormtroopers carried E-11 rifles throughout the Galactic Civil War. The design was based on that of the DC-15 series of blaster rifles, carbines, and pistols which were once favored by the Galactic Republic's clone troopers. Some stormtroopers were known to complain that the original E-11 had been poorly designed to compensate for recoil, leading to diminished accuracy in firefights, and preferred the carbine model instead.[1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight_II:_Jedi_Outcast)

Ok, so this was clearly a retcon to deal with the Stormtrooper effect... But, depending on the level of canon you are looking for, it could also be valid.

The, too, there is this info from [a Star Wars RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gundark%27s_Fantastic_Technology:_Personal_Gear):
[image]

Comment: The fact that an EM based weapon has "recoil" seems to be a significantly bigger issue than what the retcon was   meant to address :)

Comment: Probably caused by some secret sub-atomic particles that will be addressed under the Disney reign.  Will also explain why they have to bank when they turn in space, too :)

Comment: [SFF SE: Why does Millennium Falcon bank when turning in vacuum?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/why-does-millennium-falcon-bank-when-turning-in-vacuum) :)

Comment: @dvk - Ah, but a retcon could make that more addressable to the common man.  You know -- [disney viewers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHJbSvidohg)...